# Extended Event Reported Error Login Timeout

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, extended-events

While poking around for a specific event I found myself discovering an error happening every second. 
At the moment I cannot find any more information about the error as it only gets displayed in the extended events and no information is recorded either in the error log or event viewer. I can't also seem to find any application side effects that could potentially help me troubleshooting.

Has anyone seen such thing ?
Any ideas how to start troubleshooting this ?

@@Version / OS 2012 R2
Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP4) (KB4018073) - 11.0.7001.0 (X64) 
    Aug 15 2017 10:23:29 
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
    Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3  (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)

**Error reported** 
[image]

message Network error code 0x2746 occurred while establishing a connection; the connection has been closed. This may have been caused by client or server login timeout expiration. Time spent during login: total 2 ms, enqueued 0 ms, network writes 0 ms, network reads 1 ms, establishing SSL 0 ms, network reads during SSL 0 ms, network writes during SSL 0 ms, secure calls during SSL 0 ms, enqueued during SSL 0 ms, negotiating SSPI 0 ms, network reads during SSPI 0 ms, network writes during SSPI 0 ms, secure calls during SSPI 0 ms, enqueued during SSPI 0 ms, validating login 0 ms, including user-defined login processing 0 ms. [CLIENT: ::1]

Comment: Network error code `0x2746` translates to `dec: 10054` which is error `An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.`. Network address `::1` is the IPv6 loopback address. So to me, from the error, it looks like something local on the server attempting to connect ad being hit by a firewall.

Comment: @SeanGallardy-Microsoft thank you for your reply , much appreciated. Since no logging is done anywhere else apart from the extended event , is there any recommended way to troubleshoot this ? What would be the best way to find out what is actually causing this issue ? Thank you

Comment: Was there any solution to this?